# KeyError won't compare the keys

Tags: python

It shows error. What did I do wrong?

Error:

```
wordDict[word]+=1, KeyError: 'Mental'
```

My program:

```
import os

def func():
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\dinah\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\nlpPair")

    with open("covid1.dat","r") as rfile:
        d1 = rfile.read()

    bow1 = d1.split(" ")
    print("\n\t\t ---ni split words from d1 --- \n")
    print(bow1)

    wordSet= {'COVID-19', 'mental', 'symptom', 'pandemic', 'infection'}

    wordDict = dict.fromkeys(wordSet, 0)
    print(wordDict)

    for word in bow1:
        wordDict[word]+=1

    print(wordDict)
```

The content of `covid1.dat` file:

```
Mental health symptoms among American veterans during the COVID-19 Pandemic.

We examined the symptom trajectories of posttraumatic stress disorder (PTSD), depression, and anxiety among 1,230 American veterans assessed online one month prior to the COVID-19 outbreak in the United States (February 2020) through the next year (August 2020, November 2020, February 2021). Veterans slightly increased mental health symptoms over time and those with pre-pandemic alcohol and cannabis use disorders reported greater symptoms compared to those without. Women and racial/ethnic minority veterans reported greater symptoms pre-pandemic but less steep increases over time compared to men and white veterans. Findings point to the continued need for mental health care efforts with veterans.
```

Comment: In other words ;¬) - `wordDict[word]+=1` assumes `word` is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an entry in the dictionary before that entry exists.

`wordDict[word]+=1` expands to `wordDict[word] = wordDict[word] + 1`. The first time you use word, `wordDict[word]` has not yet been set to anything, therefore you cannot add one to it.

To fix it, you can use a `defaultdict` or more simply, use the default value parameter in `dict.get`:

```
wordDict[word] = wordDict.get(word, 0) + 1
```

Comment: I still don't think this is quite right. Reading between the lines, I think the OP only wants to count words if they were one of the ones in `wordSet`